# struts2: enum in IF

Tags: java, struts2, el, ognl

How does the following Java condition translate into `s:if test="..."` in *struts2*?

```
if(company.getAffiliateId().asInt() != com.foo.bar.Affiliates.XYZ.asInt()){
 // do something
}
```

*company.getAffiliateId()* returns `BigDecimal`

*com.foo.bar.Affiliates* is an `enum`

This doesn't work:

```
<s:if test="%{company.affiliateId.asInt() != com.foo.bar.Affiliates.XYZ.asInt() }">
   alert("do something");
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `toString` method to compare `enums`.

```
<s:if test="ENUM.toString() == 'some_enum_as_string'">
```

And if you want to use `enums` in JSP

```
<s:if test="@package.ENUM@enumvalue.toString() == 'some_enum_as_string'">
```

Answer (score 4):

Got it, this works for me:

```
<s:if test="%{company.affiliateId != @com.foo.bar.Affiliates@XZY.asBigDecimal() }">
```

Comment: I think the enum class was generated based on a database table. There are no static methods in it:    private int id;
    private Affiliates(int id) { this.id = id; }
    public BigDecimal asBigDecimal() { return BigDecimal.valueOf(id); }
    public int asInt() { return id; }